# angle of rotation of a $3\times 3$ matrix about axis of $3\times 1$ vector.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, rotations, matrix-calculus

Matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 &0\\  0& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$$ rotates a vector about axis $B=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ by an angle of rotation?
Where I can find relevant information.
and elementary methods to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Well done, you phrased your question in such a way that it is formally on topic, being a request for references, and you soon received the answers you were really interested in, to the underlying math problem, with zero reference in them.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the vector B is fixed by the transformation; it is the the axis about which the rotation occurs. Now note that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ 0    \\ 0    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\longrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\ 1    \\  0    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\longrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\ 0    \\ 1    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\longrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ 0    \\ 0    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Does that help ?

[image]

EDIT: 
The following three vectors are all in the plane whose normal is $B$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ -1    \\ 0    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\longrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\ 1    \\  -1    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\longrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1  \\ 0    \\ 1    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\longrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ -1    \\ 0    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use $ \cos \theta = \frac{a \cdot b}{ \mid a \mid \mid b \mid}$ to calculate the angle between them.

Comment: I'm not able to visualize this problem.

Comment: Could you please make me clear this problem further

Comment: The three standard axes rotate to one another, around the fixed vector $B$.

Comment: What this matrix represent in space

Comment: Please suggest me reference

Comment: How to calculate angle of rotation mathematically

Comment: Your matrix represents a rotation through $120^{o}$ about the vector $(1,1,1)$. A ref ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group ... I will edit an explanation of how to derive the angle into my answer.

Comment: Yes I understood 120. But is it correct? Others says 0 or 2pi

Comment: 120 is correct. 0/2π is incorrect.

Comment: I think correct answer should be 90 degree.  Since rotating vectors given by matrix are orthogonal to its axis Vector B

Comment: Plz correct if I'm wrong

Comment: The grammatical structure of your question makes it a bit ambigous. If you are asking for the angle through which the vector $B$ rotates then the answer is indeed $0$ ($B$ is the axis of rotation, so of  course it does not move). If you are asking for the angle of rotation of the transformation (which is my understanding & would seem a more sensible question) then the answer is indeed $120^{o}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $B'$ as the image of $B$:

$B' = A\cdot B$

Now calculate the angle $\beta$ between vectors $B$ and $B'$ using

$\cos\beta=\frac{B\cdot B'}{||B||\cdot ||B'||}$

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you provided, we can find the image of B on A:
$AB =  \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0 \\0&1 &0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$

Now, $|AB||B|\cos(\theta) = (AB).B \Rightarrow \theta = \arccos(1) \therefore \theta = 0 \text{ rad}, 2\pi \text{ rad}$

Comment: Thanks. What this matrix represent in space?

Comment: I believe this answer isn't answering the desired question. The matrix leaves $B$ unchanged, that much is trivial. Thus, exactly, it will rotate any other vector _around_ $B$; I think the question is _by how much_

Comment: Can you please explain @Alex Meiburg

Comment: I think it should be 90 degree. Rotating vectors are orthogonal to vector B